# How can I call a function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab

I have called a C++ function from matlab.
I do not know how to run in C++ 2010

in matlab the function command is

```
>> y = kalman01(z);
```

in C++, I know only this one

```
void kalman01(const double z[2], double y[2])
```

so How I use `kalman01.cpp` to pass an input to get output and display output `y`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the function code to do operation on z array to obtain y array.
The input of the function are an array z, that is declared const and then you can't modify it, and an array y, that contains the result of the operation performed in the function.
Now I write a simple example:

```
void kalman01(const double z[2], double y[2])
{
     y[0] = z[0] * 2;
     y[1] = z[1] * 2;
     cout << y[0] << "  " << y[1] << endl;
}
```

this function take z array e return an array with elements multiplied by 2. In main function, you write this:

```
double y[2] = {0};
kalman01(z,y);
```